# Can you scale canvas resolution without scaling objects, or translate objects relative to resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity, and would like the resolution be able to be scaled, (as long as the resolution adheres to a 16:9 ratio) and I used the "Scale With Screen Size" option in the canvas to scale the resolution. The issue is that I have canvas objects that move at a specific rate, but when the resolution is scaled differently the object movement becomes messed up, as the objects are also scaled differently.

So, is it possible to scale resolution without scaling the size of the objects? Or, alternatively, how do you translate objects relative to current resolution?